# saving a form data as txt file or json to a server location

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I want to submit a form data as key value pair in a json or text file format on the server location from the UI by entering the respective fields. I have tried some ways but no luck yet. Any suggestions please? Attaching my code for your reference.`

```js
function saveTalend() {
var location = document.getElementById('loc_st').value;
var sqlFileName = document.getElementById('txtfilePath').value;
var tableName = document.getElementById('dest_table').value;
var modeTal = document.getElementById('dest_mode').value;
var appName = e.name.value;

 var data = `input {
  application_name = "${appName}"
  location_talend = "${location}"
  hql_name = "${sqlFileName}"
  table_name = "${tableName}",
  mode = "${modeTal}"

 }`;
 e.nest_talend.value = tal_js.toString();
 e.action="/talend";
 return true;
}


app.post('/talend', function (req, res) {
    console.log("enetered talend")
    var app_name = '';

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'content-type': 'text/plain'
        });
        var oldpath = files.sqlfile.path;
        var base_path = 'C:\Projects';
        var newpath = '';
        app_name = fields.name.toString();
        if (/^win/i.test(process.platform)) {
            //windows is not perfectly yet but unix works without any issues
            //newpath = 'C://Users//atalap//' + files.sqlfile.name;
            newpath = process.env.USERPROFILE + '\\' + files.sqlfile.name;
            console.log("user Home path " + process.env.HOMEPATH + " HOME " + process.env.HOMEPATH + " USERPROFILE" + process.env.USERPROFILE);
        } else {
            newpath = base_path + app_name + '/hql/' + files.sqlfile.name;
        }
        var tal_js = fields.nest_talend.toString();
        console.log("hocon " + tal_js);
        // shell.mkdir('-p', base_path + appName + '/conf');
        shell.mkdir('-p', base_path + app_name + '/hql');
        // shell.rm('-rf', base_path + appName + '/hql/*');

        // var conf_file = base_path + appName + '/conf/' + appName + '.conf';

        fs.writeFileSync(tal_js, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                console.log("form data written to " + tal_js);
            }
        });

        fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });

        console.log('last part of form.parse');
    });
    // res.redirect('./form.html');
    return;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="data" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select class="form-control" id="loc_st" name="loc_st">
                    <option>Spark</option>
                    <option>Talend</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container" id="myHeader">
                <div class="form-group col childContainer">

                    <label for="fileToLoad0" class="btn button1 btn-md btn-secondary">Import</label>
                  
                   <input type="file" id="fileToLoad0" name="sqlfile" style="display:none" onchange='openFile(event)'>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" id="txtfilePath" style="width: 30%; margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 15px;" />


                    <div class="form-group col-lg-8 rep">
                        <hr />
                        <textarea id="txtSql" class="form-control clearBox fileContentBox" name="inputTextToSave" rows="5"
                            onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Enter HQL here..</textarea>
                        <br />
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="table">Table</label>
                                <input type="text" name="table" class="form-control clearBox" id="inputName1" id="table"
                                    placeholder="Table Name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="mode">Mode</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="inputName2">
                                    <option>Overwrite</option>
                                    <option>Append</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 <button type="submit" formaction="/talend" id="submit_tld" class="btn tal_btn btn-md btn-secondary" onClick="return saveTalend()">Save Talend</button>
                  <input type="hidden" id="talend_se" value="0" name="nest_talend" />
```

`
If you have any reference for this or any inputs are welcome.
TIA.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I am unable to get the data stored on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use `shell.mkdir` in your code but `shell` is not defined anywhere - at least in the sample code you have provided. Why don't you use `fs.mkdir` instead?
Also, you need a `\` between: `base_path` and `app_name`:

`base_path + '\' + app_name`

since `base_path = 'C:\Projects'`.

Better yet, use `path.join` to make sure that the joined path will not be platform specific:

You can also use: `JSON.stringify(fields.nest_talend)` instead of `.toString()` since if `fields.nest_talend` is an object it will return a string equal to: `'[object Object]'`.

**Finally, your call to `fs. writeFileSync` is wrong. Since the file will be written syncronously, no callback is needed. Also, the first parameter needs to be the file location to be written. Try this:**

`fs.writeFileSync('location-path/file.json', tal_js, 'utf8');`

I think after these changes your code will work.

Comment: I get an error on this line which says callback must be a function. saved = fs.writeFileSync('location-path/file.json', tal_js, 'utf8');

Comment: Try this in a node shell:
`a = {a:1, b:2}`

`fs.writeFileSync('path/data.json', JSON.stringify(a), 'utf-8');`
Does it work?

Comment: No this is the error i get. a = {a:1, b:2} fs.writeFileSync('path/data.json', JSON.stringify(a), 'utf-8');
At line:1 char:9
+ a = {a:1, b:2} fs.writeFileSync('path/data.json', JSON.stringify(a),  ...
+         ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:50
+ a = {a:1, b:2} fs.writeFileSync('path/data.json', JSON.stringify(a),  ...
+                                                  ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:51
+ ...  {a:1, b:2} fs.writeFileSync('path/data.json', JSON.stringify(a), 'ut ...

Comment: The value for this console i get as 0. console.log("hocon " + tal_js);

Comment: Did you just copy-paste everything as one line??

Comment: well you shouldn't.
 
`a = {a:1, b:2};` must be a separate line from 

`fs.writeFileSync('path/data.json', JSON.stringify(a), 'utf-8');`.

Also, don't just copy paste, replace 'path' above with a path location that exists on your computer.